# I am trying to predict value of a an output through KN regression but getting an error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

[This is the code used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpxEq.jpg)

Also posted below is the error which is received

```
File "C:\Users\Manoj\Videos\KNN.py", line 277, in <module>
    yhat = model.predict(new_data)
  File "C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\_regression.py", line 241, in predict
    y_pred = np.mean(_y[neigh_ind], axis=1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in mean
  File "C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 3432, in mean
    return _methods._mean(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
  File "C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 180, in _mean
    ret = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, where=where)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dataframe probably contains string which knn does not support